# How to form dictionary with string and numpy array?

Tags: python, dictionary

How to interchange key-value pair of my `dict` where key is string and value is `numpy` array

```
word2index = {'think': array([[9.56090081e-05]]), 
              'apple':array([[0.00024469]])}
```

Now I need output like this

```
index2word = {array([[9.56090081e-05]]):'think', 
              array([[0.00024469]]):'apple'}
```

Comment: Not a good idea to have a list of array as a `key` in the dict.

Comment: [Why Lists Can't Be Dictionary Keys in Python](https://wiki.python.org/moin/DictionaryKeys)

Comment: You can't use mutables (such as numpy arrays) as dictionary keys.

Comment: @Sisekarthikeyan, you may consider accepting an answer that helped: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work cheers

Answer (score 3):

[Why Lists Can't Be Dictionary Keys](https://wiki.python.org/moin/DictionaryKeys)

> To be used as a dictionary key, an object must support the hash
>   function (e.g. through **hash**), equality comparison (e.g. through
>   **eq** or **cmp**)
>
> That said, the simple answer to why lists cannot be used as dictionary
>   keys is that lists do not provide a valid **hash** method.

However, using a `string representation` of the list:

```
word2index = {'think': [9.56090081e-05], 'apple': [0.00024469]}
print({repr(v):k for k,v in word2index.items()})
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
{'[9.56090081e-05]': 'think', '[0.00024469]': 'apple'}
```

**OR**:

Converting the list to a tuple:

```
print({tuple(v):k for k,v in word2index.items()})
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
{(9.56090081e-05,): 'think', (0.00024469,): 'apple'}
```

Comment: Agree for both solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if we can set numpy array as dict key, but you can use below code to interchange the disct key and values:

```
index2word = {value:key for key, value in word2index.items()}
```